# Extension of transvection

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I need your kind help in following:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Then $1 \neq \tau \in GL(V)$ is said to be a transvection if there is a hyperplane $W$ in $V$ such that $\tau|_W=I_W$ and $\tau(v)-v \in W$ for all $v \in V$.

Suppose that $V$ is a subspace of $V_1$, $v \in V_1 \setminus V$ and $\tau$ is a transvection of $V$ with fixed hyperplane $W$. Show that $\tau$ can be extended to a transvection $\tau_1$ of $V_1$ whose fixed plane $W_1$ contains $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix subspace $U$ of $V_1$ such that $V_1 = V \oplus U$ (such a choice is not unique). Then every $v_1 \in V_1$ has a unique decomposition $v_1 = v + u$ for some $v\in V$ and $u\in U$. Then map $\tau_1$ defined by $\tau_1(v + u) = \tau(v) + u$ is a transvection on $V_1$ with fixed plane containing $W$.